# Increase and decrease a variable until a number is reached in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

How can I increase and decrease a variable in Javascript until 100 and when 100 is reached it should start decreasing.

So `accuracyBarValue` should start in 0, increase to 100, and when 100 is reached it should go to 0, and then repeat procedure.

This in intervals of 10.

I use this in a very simple JS game, where this value is used to increase and decrease a PowerBar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is another take on this:

```js
var up = true;
var value = 0;
var increment = 10;
var ceiling = 100;

function PerformCalc() {
  if (up == true && value <= ceiling) {
    value += increment

    if (value == ceiling) {
      up = false;
    }
  } else {
      up = false
      value -= increment;

      if (value == 0) {
        up = true;
      }
  }

  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Value: ' + value + '<br />';
}
setInterval(PerformCalc, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

**Code**

```js
let i = 100;
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(Math.abs((i+=10)%200 - 100))
}, 1000);
```

**Deconstruction**

1. `i+=10` → `i` gets indefinitely increased by 10 on every tick
2. `%100` → modulo of double the max value (division remaining ex. `10 % 6 = 4`)
3. `- 100` → remove the range (so the numbers will always be between 100 and -100, otherwise  it would be between 0 and 6)
4. `Math.abs()` → removes the - (Makes sure the number moves from 0 to 100 and back)

**Steps Visualized**

**i++**

```
∞       .
       .
      .
     /
    /
   / 
  /
0
```

**(i+=10)%200**

```
200 
     /    /    /    .
    /    /    /    .
   /    /    /    .
  /    /    /    /
 /    /    /    /
0
```

**i++%200-100**

```
100 
  \        /\        /\
   \      /  \      /  \
0   \    /    \    /    .
     \  /      \  /      .
      \/        \/        .
-100
```

**Math.abs(i++%200-100)**

```
100 
  \    /\    /.
   \  /  \  /  .
    \/    \/    .
0
```

**Implementation Example**

```js
const max = 10;

let i = max;
const $body = document.querySelector('body');

setInterval(() => {
  const val = Math.abs(i++%(max * 2) - max);
  const $el = document.createElement('i');
  $el.style = `--i: ${i}; --val: ${val}`;
  $body.appendChild($el);
  window.scrollTo(window.innerWidth, 0);
  console.log(val);

}, 200);
```

```css
i {
  --i: 0;
  --val: 0;
  --size: 10px;
  
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size); 
  top: var(--size);
  left: calc(-10 * var(--size));
  transform: translate(
    calc(var(--i) * var(--size)),
    calc(var(--val) * var(--size))
  )
}
```

**Alternative Approaches** (Float based)

```js
Math.acos(Math.cos(i * Math.PI)) / Math.PI;
```

or

```js
Math.abs(i - Math.floor(i) - .5);
```

Where `i` is a `float` between `0` - `Infinity`. Result is a `float` as well that needs to be multiplied by your max and rounded (target value).

Comment: This is really useful. I've been scouring the web for these formulas and it's almost impossible to come up with a search phrase to get here. Thanks for taking the time to post this stuff.

Comment: @pbarney let me know what you searched for, so I can modify the answer a bit

Comment: It's hard for me to say because I used startpage to search and it does a POST instead of a GET, so my history doesn't show what I searched for. Probably something like "formula to increment a number until it reaches a certain limit and then restart." Very kludgy. I think later I looked for "increment loops" or something like that that led me here.

Comment: @meo you mentioned this in your explanatin:
"- 100 → remove the range (so the numbers will always be between 100 and -100, otherwise it would be between 0 and 6)". I get the 100 to -100 value range but in what scenario would the range in  %200 be 0 and 6?

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
document.write("The number is " + i);
document.write("<br />");
}
while (i>0)
{
    i -= 10;
    document.write("The number is " + i);
    document.write("<br />");
}
```

You can test and modify it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/BqMKS/).

Comment: If your incrementing by 10 as well, in the for loop it should be: i+=10 as in:  
for(var i=0;i<100;i+=10)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
while( i < 100 )
{
    i++;
}

while( i > -1 )
{
    i--;
}
```

You can also do other code in the `while` loops, obviously.

Comment: Well, that's incrementing by 1.  Instead of i++, it should be i+=10;

Answer (score 0):

## Using Duration and Frame Rate.

Another approach that allows you to specify the duration and frame rate. Highly useful for animations and things that happen over a period of time.

#### HTML

```
<h2>Increment Value over a Duration with a given framerate</h2>
Value: <span id="value">0</span>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var valueElement = document.getElementById('value');

var start     = 0;
var end       = 100;
var duration  = 10000; // In milliseconds (divide by 1000 to get seconds).
var framerate = 50;    // In milliseconds (divide by 1000 to get seconds).

var toAdd = ( ( end - start ) * framerate ) / duration;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var currentValue = parseFloat(valueElement.innerHTML);

  if (currentValue >= end) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    return;
  }

    valueElement.innerHTML = (!isNaN(currentValue) == true ? currentValue + toAdd : toAdd);
}, framerate);
```

#### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/joshuapinter/8uasm7ko/

I wanted to display the incremental value but you could easily wrap this up into a generic function as well.

Comment: Based on your answer, I made my addapted solution just working for integer values: https://jsfiddle.net/eLynvxt3/9/

Thank you