# countup and countdown loop

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to count from 3 down to 0 then back up to 3 in a loop. This is kind of "slider" implementation. Everything runs fine until reach the `clearInterval` from `counterry`. What am I missing?

```
var counttx = 0, // counter
    counterrx = setInterval(timerrx, 1000), // countup - start
    counterry; // countdown after reach 3

function timerrx(){
    counttx = counttx+1;
    //console.log(counttx);
    if(counttx > 2){
        counterry = setInterval(timerry, 1000); 
        clearInterval(counterrx);
    }
}

function timerry(){
   counttx = counttx-1;
   //console.log(counttx);
   if(counttx < 2){
       setInterval(timerrx, 1000);
       clearInterval(counterry);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase and decrease a variable until a number is reached in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496576/increase-and-decrease-a-variable-until-a-number-is-reached-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a single loop:

```js
let counttx = 0, countup = true;
const counter = document.getElementById('counter');

function timerr()
{
  if (countup)
  {
    ++counttx;
    
    if (counttx >= 3)
      countup = false;
  }
  else
  {
    --counttx;
    
    if (counttx <= 0)
      countup = true;
  }
  
  counter.value = counttx;
}

setInterval(timerr, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="counter" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 5):

**Code**

```js
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(Math.abs(i++%6 - 3))
}, 1000);
```

**Deconstruction**

1. `i++` → `i` gets indefinitely increased by one on every tick
2. `%6` → modulo of double the max vvalue (division remaining ex. `10 % 6 = 4`)
3. `- 3` → remove the range (so the numbers will always be between 3 and -3, otherwise  it would be between 0 and 6)
4. `Math.abs()` → removes the - (Makes sure the number moves from 0 to 3 and back)

**Steps Visualized**

**i++**

```
∞       .
       .
      .
     /
    /
   / 
  /
0
```

**i++%6**

```
6 
     /    /    /    .
    /    /    /    .
   /    /    /    .
  /    /    /    /
 /    /    /    /
0
```

**i++%6-3**

```
3 
  \        /\        /\
   \      /  \      /  \
0   \    /    \    /    .
     \  /      \  /      .
      \/        \/        .
-3
```

**Math.abs(i++%6-3)**

```
3 
  \    /\    /.
   \  /  \  /  .
    \/    \/    .
0
```

**Example output for the 8 first iterations:**

1. `i` 0

   1. `0%6` 0
   2. `0-3` -3
   3. `Math.abs(-3)` 3
2. `i` 1

   1. `1%6` 1
   2. `1-3` -2
   3. `Math.abs(-2)` 2
3. `i` 2

   1. `2%6` 2
   2. `2-3` -1
   3. `Math.abs(-1)` 1
4. `i` 3

   1. `3%6` 3
   2. `3-3` 0
   3. `Math.abs(0)` 0
5. `i` 4

   1. `4%6` 4
   2. `4-3` 1
   3. `Math.abs(1)` 1
6. `i` 5

   1. `5%6` 5
   2. `5-3` 2
   3. `Math.abs(2)` 2
7. `i` 6

   1. `6%6` 0
   2. `0-3` -3
   3. `Math.abs(-3)` 3
8. `i` 7

   1. `7%6` 1
   2. `1-3` -2
   3. `Math.abs(-2)` 2

**Implementation Example**

```js
const max = 10
let i = max;
const $body = document.querySelector('body');

setInterval(() => {
  const val = Math.abs(i++%(max * 2) - max);
  const $el = document.createElement('i');
  $el.style = `--i: ${i}; --val: ${val}`;
  $body.appendChild($el);
  window.scrollTo(window.innerWidth, 0);
  console.log(val);

}, 200);
```

```css
i {
  --i: 0;
  --val: 0;
  --size: 10px;
  
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size); 
  top: var(--size);
  left: calc(-10 * var(--size));
  transform: translate(
    calc(var(--i) * var(--size)),
    calc(var(--val) * var(--size))
  )
}
```

**Alternative Approaches**

```js
Math.acos(Math.cos(i * Math.PI)) / Math.PI;
```

or

```js
Math.abs(i - Math.floor(i) - .5);
```

Where `i` is a `float` between `0` - `Infinity`. Result is a `float` as well that needs to be multiplied by your max and rounded (target value).

Comment: Try adding a small description for your answer.

Comment: @MartínCanaval did my best, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic could look something like the below, and you can adjust this for the interval timers in javascript.

```
int counter=0;
int delta=1;
bool finished=false;
while(!finished)
{
   counter+=delta;
   if(counter==3)
   {
      delta=-1;
   }
   if(counter==0)
   {
      delta=1;
   }
   if(condition to end loop is met)
   {
      finished=true;
   }

}
```